# SecondaryTable without DiscriminatorValue

Tags: java, jpa

Main Common table:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="X__TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class UsersEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "USER_ID", length = 15, nullable = false)  
  private String userId;
}
```

Project common table:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_USER")
@SecondaryTable( name = "CUSTOMER_USER", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID"))
public class CustomerUserEntity extends UsersEntity {
...
}
```

Project customes types...:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TYPEA")
public class TypeAEntity extends CustomerUserEntity { 
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TYPEB")
public class TypeBEntity extends CustomerUserEntity {
}
```

**Optional customerUser = customerUserRepository.findById("BD6UXLM8O01");**

The problem is the following:

How could I remove from the select a "CustomerUserEntity" ?

```
select
        customerus0_.user_id as user_id2_37_0_,
        ...
        customerus0_1_.active as active1_5_0_,
        ...        
    from
        users customerus0_ 
    left outer join
        customer_user customerus0_1_ 
            on customerus0_.user_id=customerus0_1_.customer_user_id 
    where
        customerus0_.user_id=? 
        and customerus0_.x__type in (
            'CustomerUserEntity', 'TYPEA', 'TYPEB'
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh My GOD:
The solution:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_USER")
@SecondaryTable( name = "CUSTOMER_USER", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID"))

@DiscriminatorValue("null")

public class CustomerUserEntity extends UsersEntity {
}
```

and select:

```
...
where
        customerus0_.user_id=? 
        and (
            customerus0_.x__type is null 
            or customerus0_.x__type in (
                'TYPEA', 'TYPEB'
            )
        )
```

Example6:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I moved the SecondaryTable from CustomerEntity to UsersEntity, and the CustomerEntity was changed Embeddable.

UserEntity:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="X__TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@SecondaryTable( name = "CUSTOMER_USER", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_USER_ID"))
public class UsersEntity {
  
  @Id
  @Column(name = "USER_ID", length = 15, nullable = false)
  @NotNull
  private String userId; 
  ...
  @Embedded 
  public CustomerUserEntity customerUserEntity;
}
```

CustomerUserEntity:

```
@Embeddable
public class CustomerUserEntity {
  
  @Column(name = "CUSTOMER", length = 35, nullable = false, table = "CUSTOMER_USER")
  @Size(max = 35)
  @ColumnDetailedInformation(columnLabel = "Ügyfél")
  @NotNull
  private String customer;
  ...
}
```

And TypeAEntity, TypeBEntity

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TYPEA")
public class TypeAEntity extends UsersEntity { 
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TYPEB")
public class TypeBEntity extends UsersEntity {
}
```

I'm so sad, becase I didn't want to modify the common entity (UserEntity).

Köszi Csabi a tippet! :)